# Lazyload inside bootstrap panel group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using a collapsible bootstrap panel group and one extra div I added with a class name jscroll-inner just after the panel-group start. Jscroll-inner is reuired to load more panels.

Now the problem is, collapse is not working properly. Means if I click one panel to open , then the other panel should get close. But here all panels are getting open.

Please let me know if know if anybody can help on this.

Here is the code

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
     <div class="jscroll-inner">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            Collapsible Group 1</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
            Collapsible Group 2</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
            Collapsible Group 3</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="jscroll-inner">
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            Collapsible Group 1</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
            Collapsible Group 2</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
            Collapsible Group 3</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```